# Capture a photo, save temporarily, and open as bitmap

Tags: flutter, android-bitmap

I'm new to Flutter.

### What I need:

Open a photo from android temp folder and convert to bitmap.

### **What am I doing:**

Following this tutorial: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

1. I'm invoking the "takePicture" method in "CameraController" which
   saves the photo in a temporary file;
2. I open the file and try to convert to bitmap:

Code:

```
final Image photo = Image.file(File(imagePath));  
final AssetImage image = photo.image;  
final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.fromAssetImage(image);
```

### **What happens:**

> local> /data/data/io.flutter.plugins.firebasemlvisionexample/cache/2019-08-19 14:14:58.720970.png.
>   I/flutter ( 7943): type 'FileImage' is not a subtype of type 'AssetImage'

**If you use "Bitmap.fromImage(photo)", VScode displays:**

> The argument type 'Image (where Image is defined in. 
>   /Users/luis/development/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/image.dart)'
>   can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Image (where Image is defined
>   in
>   /Users/luis/development/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/ui/painting.dart)'.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
Image.asset('images/cat.png')
```

[Images.asset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.asset.html)

Comment: I am saving the image in the temporary folder, to work this way I would have to save in the "assets" folder and then manually delete the file?

Comment: What package of Bitmap are you using?